# Slide Rule Marking Proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The basic slide rule scale starts at 1, runs through all the positive numerals, then ends at 1.

How are the distances between these whole numbers on a slide rule proportioned?

Comment: logarithmically

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you find any answer helpful, please remember to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The slide rules are distanced logarithmically. Look closely. [image]

Comment: Since slide rules help you compute logarithms

Comment: slide rules help you multiply, because multiplying two numbers corresponds to adding their logarithms

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I agree

Comment: The answers have described how slide rules work and have stated that the distances between the numbers on the rule are determined logarithmically.  How do you calculate that distance?

Comment: @jba See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK57O0s_yyA for more information.

Comment: I appreciate the youtube clip. Now, how to calculate the base 10 logs for 2 and 3? ...And here's how!  https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-base-10-logarithm-of-2, then scroll down to the entry of George C.

Comment: @jba Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @jba This is a bit long, so let's start a chatroom instead of commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, they are proportiened logarithmically. This allows you to multiply (divide and list proportions of) two numbers using the slide rule.

Lets call $D$ the distance between the first $1_1 \equiv 1$ and the second $1_2 \equiv 10$. Then the distances are proportiened in such a way that the distance $d(1_1,x)$ between $1_1$ an some other number $x$ is
$$
d(1_1 , x) = D \log_{10}(x)
$$
( with this we have $d(1_1 , 1_2) = d(1_1 , 10) = D \log_{10}(10) = D$ )

You can now multiply by adding distances:
$$
d(1_1 , x) + d(1_1 , y) = D \log_{10}(x) + D \log_{10}(y) = D \log_{10}(x \cdot y) = 
d(1_1 , x \cdot y) 
$$
Reading off the numbers $x,y$ happens on the ruler. Adding the distances happens by using the sliding part in the middle and reading off the result $x \cdot y$ can again be made on the ruler.